# How to create a drilleable bar graph in jsp page using open source charts API

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, highcharts, jfreechart

We are developing a web application using Spring+Tiles. We have a requirement that we have to create a bar graph in a jsp page. We searched a lot on web regarding this issue. Means how we can create a bar graph using Open source Charts API. We found many suggested APIs like JFreeChart, charts4j and etc.

But we are not sure which one to use. Actually our requirement is we have to create a bar graph which can be drillable.

Please help us. If you could give any examples that will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use the rest services and send the `json` to highcharts OR D3.js OR DDChart, its the best thing to do in your case below link can do what you want :

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown

- Highchart (licence) : http://jsfiddle.net/yPVX9/2/
- D3 (free) : http://jsfiddle.net/mcuepavh/1/
- DDChart (free) : http://kiersimmons.com/DDChart/index.html

Comment: To use highcharts should I pruchase it?

Comment: No, its free for some extent, most of things come in free version.

Comment: Actually we cannot use this for Non-Porfit organization. Can you Please suggest with any other answer.

Comment: Highchart is free for non-commercial ,Non-Porfit organization.. check http://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts.html for details

Comment: @AmeyJadiye: Really I liked D3 and DDChart. Can you please tell me how to use DDChart.

Comment: glad you liked d3.js, i love it, for DDchart check tab `plugin option`, you have to do some manupulation with javascript there.

Comment: Let me try champion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try FusionCharts for a drill down chart.
Have a look to this and you can use this in your application : [Fusion Charts Linked Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/features/linkedcharts-for-drill-down/). Regarding licensing issues,you may get in touch Sales Team.

Apart from that, you can use [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) . Start from the basics say try creating a small rectangle, fill some color, opacity, binding some events,etc. With a day effort you can make a simple bar chart. Once you make a bar chart, attach an event to clear your container and redraw another bar chart with the drill down data. Thats the concept you need for your drill-down.

Having said that, I would still recommend you to use Fusion Charts because they takes care of some smart things  - like space management of the bars, the intervals, the colour codes of the bars(if not hard-coded), axis part... Its a finished product which abstracts you from the technical obstructions and give your application a beautiful add-on.